# External Javascript/CSS not loading in lightning component

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service, libraries

When my sandbox was updated from Winter 17 to Spring 17 all external js and css which are stored in static resource are not getting loaded in lightning component. Below is the error that we are getting in google chrome developer console -

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://intouch--dmkts2.lightning.force.com/JS/jquery-2.2.4.min.js

After looking the url from which system try to load external JS/CSS is not correct. In the above url "JS" and "assets" are folder name inside static resource zip file(App_Resource). It doesnt contain static resource name. Ideally it should contain resource name. Ideally it should be "intouch--dmkts2.lightning.force.com/App_Resource/JS/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"

[image]